# OpenX: Can't link zones to local banners, despite zones being defined in campaign

Tags: openx

I've recently encountered a problem with OpenX. I can no longer choose zones to link to my banners. The zones simply won't show up. But this seems to only occur when I have uploaded a local image.

I have chosen the zones for each campaign properly, but despite that, the zones won't show up under the banners for the most recent advertiser accounts that I have created.

Strangely enough, I tested one recent advertiser account by choosing to create a banner with an external html url. The zones showed up fine. When I removed the external html url and uploaded a local image, the zones disappeared again.

I thought it might be an image permissions problem, but all of the images for all campaigns are in the same folder, and I've compared all images. They all have the same permissions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image dimensions probably do not fit the dimensions of the zone.

You can set the zone dimensions to "*" if you to push banners of different sizes in one zone.

When you used an HTML/JS banner OpenX has no way of finding the dimensions of that banner so it allows you to assign it to any zone that is linked to the banners campaign.

Comment: Thanks.  That turned out to be exactly the problem; the images were one pixel smaller than the zone.  Grrr.